# Is it possible to get all transactions from a single address with bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

Is it possible to get all transactions from a single address with bitcoind?

Answer (score 1):

For an address that is in your wallet, you can use the `listreceivedbyaddress` command. You would use the command as follows to get the transactions related to an address `<address>`:

```
bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 0 true true <address>
```

The `0` means list all transactions, including unconfirmed ones. The first `true` indicates that the address should still appear in the output even if there are no transactions; it just won't have any transactions listed under it. The second `true` means to include watching only addresses in the output. This only matters if your address is a watch only address.

If the address is not in your wallet, you cannot get all transactions for an address. This is because that would require maintaining an address index which Bitcoin Core does not do. Address indexes require more computing power and are not useful to the functioning of the node.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a program in Python3 that allows you to search for any address on bitcoin core whether it belongs to your wallet or not.

Here is the github link:

https://github.com/ORP967/Bitcoin_Core_RPC_par_address

Let me know what you think or if you have any improvements you might have.

Answer (score -1):

You can use command "listtransaction".

http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/listtransactions

Good luck =)

Comment: No, that only lists transactions that affect your own wallet.

Answer (score -1):

yes. try this command:
**bitcoin-cli -regtest getrawtransaction  1**.

This command will give you all transactions for the required address.

Comment: That is not at all what getrawtransaction does. It gives you the raw transaction for a specific transaction. It has nothing to do with addresses.